# Google Calendar API - Undefined symbols for architecture i386

Tags: ios, google-api, xcode6, google-calendar-api, linker-errors

I am trying to integrate Google Calendar API for 2 days. I have been following Quick tutorial from [Google's Official Guide](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/ios). Up till now I have successfully compiled my workspace without the use of Calendar API.

When I try to use it, I get following linker errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLQueryCalendar", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in DashboardController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLServiceCalendar", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in DashboardController.o
  "_deflate", referenced from:
      l001 in GoogleSignIn(GTMNSData+zlib.o)
  "_deflateEnd", referenced from:
      l001 in GoogleSignIn(GTMNSData+zlib.o)
  "_deflateInit2_", referenced from:
      l001 in GoogleSignIn(GTMNSData+zlib.o)
  "_inflate", referenced from:
      l002 in GoogleSignIn(GTMNSData+zlib.o)
  "_inflateEnd", referenced from:
      l002 in GoogleSignIn(GTMNSData+zlib.o)
  "_inflateInit2_", referenced from:
      l002 in GoogleSignIn(GTMNSData+zlib.o)
  "_kGTLAuthScopeCalendarReadonly", referenced from:
      -[DashboardController createAuthController] in DashboardController.o
  "_kGTLCalendarOrderByStartTime", referenced from:
      -[DashboardController fetchEvents] in DashboardController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
```

I have added `libGTLTouchStaticLib.a` to my main project. Moreover, these are architecture settings in sub projects.

**GTMSessionFetcher**

[image]

**GTL**

[image]

Simple line of code I tried to use are:

```
- (void)fetchEvents {
    GTLQueryCalendar *query = [GTLQueryCalendar queryForEventsListWithCalendarId:@"primary"];
    query.maxResults = 10;
    query.timeMin = [GTLDateTime dateTimeWithDate:[NSDate date]
                                         timeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];;
    query.singleEvents = YES;
    query.orderBy = kGTLCalendarOrderByStartTime;

    [self.service executeQuery:query
                      delegate:self
             didFinishSelector:@selector(displayResultWithTicket:finishedWithObject:error:)];
}
```

Comment: try adding -ObjC in other linker flags

Comment: are you running on simulator. Have you tested on device? i386 is for simulator

Comment: I can't right now. I dont have device, so testing on simulator.

Comment: check once on device. i386 is for simulators only or in valid architectures where arm64 etc are written, add i386 also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally resolved. I copied all `implementation (.m) files` from the path `google-api-objectivec-client/Source/Services/Calendar/Generated/` into the main project. I didn't need to copy the header files, as the classes had already been detected.

Moreover, I need to add `libz.dylib` framework as well to make all errors gone. Google should have mentioned these steps in their docs as well.

Hopefully it helps someone in future!